# Conditional Joins in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, join, conditional-statements

I have a parent child table relationship. In the example below Foo has a FooID and a nullable ParentFooID that points to a parent record.

The Bar table is always linked to the parent record. This is the SQL I use to get the result.

```
Select * from Foo f
JOIN  Bar b
  ON b.FooID =  
     CASE 
       WHEN f.ParentFooID is null
         THEN f.FooID
       ELSE f.ParentFooID
     END
```

I'm having a bit of trouble getting this into a LINQ query. I'd like to avoid a cross join like the following:

```
    var q = from f in Foo 
            from b in Bar 
            where  b.FooID == (f.ParentFooID ?? f.FooID)
```

Cheers,

Daniel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your specific example is using `CASE` to fall back to a non-null value, which is really just a `COALESCE`. In which case, this works:

```
var q = from f in dc.Foos
        join
        b in dc.Bars
        on
        (f.ParentFooID ?? f.FooID)
        equals
        b.FooID
        into grouped
        select grouped;
```

Which translates into:

```
SELECT ...
FROM [dbo].[Foo] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Bar] AS [t1]
ON (COALESCE([t0].[ParentFooID],[t0].[FooID])) = [t1].[FooID]
ORDER BY [t0].[FooID], [t1].[BarID]
```

The key is the left outer join on `COALESCE(case1, case2)`, so the expression converter does seem to understand that.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't directly answer your question but wouldn't the original query be better phrased without the case conditional as:

```
Select * 
from Foo f
JOIN Bar b ON b.FooID = f.FooID
Where f.ParentFooID is null
UNION ALL
Select * 
from Foo f
JOIN Bar b ON b.FooID = f.ParentFooID
Where f.ParentFooID is not null
```

In which case, the LINQ expression should be easier?

Answer (score 0):

Some complex scenarios aren't well mapped by LINQ; I would suggest that joining onto a `case` is one of them. Re doing it as a cross join... have your profiled it? (i.e. the subsequent SQLfrom the `from ... from ...` (LINQ) vs the complex `join` (TSQL)? In many cases the profiler can get the same (or similar) query plan from the old-style approaches.

Comment: I have profiled the from...from scenario and yes, it does result in a cross join which does do a index scan (not a seek) so it's going to perform a lot worse than the original query which is doing a index seek.